# ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching filter(::typeof(isfinite), ::Base.SkipMissing{Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}})

Tags: julia, gwas

```
@time PRRS_outCPi=runMCMC(PRRS_model,
    phenotypes,
    methods="BayesC", 
    missing_phenotypes=true,
    Pi= 0.999,
    estimatePi=true, 
    estimateScale=true,
    chain_length=50000,
    burnin = 5000,
    output_heritability=true,
    output_samples_frequency=100)
```

When I try running that code it brings me that error. What could I do to get by it?

Comment: We probably need more information - how is  the model constructed, what is the `phenotypes` variable, etc. And the Stacktrace that follows the error will also be helpful. In the meantime, you could try `collect(phenotypes)` instead of just `phenotypes` in this call and see if that fixes it (this is just a shot in the dark though).

Comment: Also make sure you are running the latest version of Julia. `filter` on `skipmissing` works just fine for me in Julia 1.7.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.